# how to select/replace all elements of a row/columns in a matrix?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I know in matlab we can do `Matrix(1,:)`, and it gives us all the elements  of the first row for all the columns.
Is there anyway to do that in c++?
Like if I have `int Matrix[3][3]={{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3}};` how I can get/or replace `{1,1,1}` all together?

Comment: You can make use of a double pointer to access the sub arrays.

Comment: can you explain more how?

Comment: @Javia1492  yes the question is very similar, but non of them has a clear answer

Comment: [Take a look at `std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray), particularly the `slice` support functions.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of your matrix

```
int Matrix[3][3]={{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3}};
```

it is merely a two dimensional array. The index of an array starts with `0`. `Matrix[0]` refers to the first element, which is `{1,1,1}`. I guess this is what you were looking for.

If you want to replace the first element of the matrix then you need to replace element by element. It could be for example

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    Matrix[0][i] = 4;
```

The matrix would then be

```
int Matrix[3][3]={{4,4,4},{2,2,2},{3,3,3}};
```

In the book *The C++ Programming Language* from Bjarne Stroustrup you can find some discussion about implementing a matrix class.

Also you might find matrix implementations out there in the internet.

Since I believe you are relatively new to C++ I also suggest to learn about the STL, in particular the `vector` class, which is basically a dynamic array.

I'd also suggest to use the `array` class if you use C++11 or later.

A more advanced approach would be to use an array of pointers. This would allow you to replace an entire row. However, this would be more C and less C++. The C++ way would be to implement a matrix class.

Comment: Thanks,so using loop in the only way of doing that? no other solution?
Also when i run `cout<<Matrix[0]<<endl;` it gives me a address not the elements..

Comment: The way you declared the matrix, yes. I mentioned that you could use a more advanced approach at the end of my answer. But that requires you to learn the programming language first. I'd suggest you learn the programming languages C/C++, at least the basics. This would have spared you asking the question I believe.

Comment: How do you suggest I define a matrix so I can extract a row/column easier?